URL Redirection to Untrusted Site ('Open Redirect') (CWE ID 601)
Need solution to Veracode Flaw URL Redirection to Untrusted Site ('Open Redirect') (CWE ID 601).
Flaw is in line
Response.Redirect("~/output.aspx" + Request.Url.Query);
My function:
protected void cmdX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/output.aspx" + Request.Url.Query);
}

